# Python - How to copy a ImmutableDict to a mutable dict?

Tags: python, immutability

I'm trying to do a hard copy on a dictionary to avoid modifying the values of original one.

Here is my code:

```
import copy
d1 = {1: 1}
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d1)
d2[1] = None
```

What if `d1` is a ImmutableDict? How can I copy one and allow it to be modified?

```
import immutabledict
d1 = immutabledict.immutabledict({1: 1})
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d1)
d2[1] = None  # TypeError: 'immutabledict' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `dict` will create the copy and allow you to mutate `d2`

```
import immutabledict
d1 = immutabledict.immutabledict({1: 1})
d2 = dict(d1)
d2[1] = None
```

This correctly updates `d2` and does not change `d1`.

Comment: This copies it.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Good point. I've updated the text to reflect that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to copy use
d2 = {**d1}